# Altering Cache value based on php response of an image or html in Nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, cache

I'have a set up where a PHP script dynamically creates images based on size and the device requesting them.

Everything is working fine apart setting a higher cache expiry for images when they are loaded from PHP.

I have a location block, shown below, which checks for a static file and if it doesn't exist it passes it over to the PHP location block (Also shown below).

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;

    expires 30m;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

# Dynamic Images
location ~* \.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    expires 1M;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

Ideally I'd like a default cache-control header of 30m for all content, HTML included and then have 1M for images. Is there a way to do this given that the image files are returned based off of a PHP script?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: remove `expires 30m;` and set `Expires` header in your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i had guessed that was my best option if it wasn't possible in the config file. Just would have been nice to have the seperation